# Can you explain the difference between "complex" and a "compound" sentences to a mathematician?

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences, compound-sentences

It has already been asked, ["what is the difference between “compound” and “complex” sentence?"](http://What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20%E2%80%9Ccompound%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9Ccomplex%E2%80%9D%20sentences?) However, I am looking for an answer which appeals to a mathematical mind.

In mathematics, there are "`operators`" and "`operands`". Let us have some examples:

- In the expression `3 + 9`...

  - the plus sign (`+`) is an "operator"
  - `3` and `9` are "operands"
- In `88 * 55`, the multiplication sign (`*`) is an "operator."
- In the logical statement, `not[(P) and (Q)] if and only if [(not P) or (not Q)]` the sub-string `if and only if` is an operator.

It looks like in English, that "operators" are called "conjunctions."

I do not really understand the distinction between “compound” and “complex” sentences. It looks like sentences can follow the following patterns:

- Compound: (independent clause) (conjunction) (independent clause)
- Complex: (independent clause) (dependent clause)

It seems to me as if a dependent clause is simply an independent clause and conjunction lumped together.

In the mathematical expression `1 + 3` we might say that:

- "`1`" is an "independent clause"
- "`+ 3`" is a "dependent clause"

You can draw the boundaries where one-sub-string ends, and the next begins, anywhere that you like:

- `(1)(+3)`...... (independent clause)(dependent clause)
- `(1)(+)(3)` ......... (independent clause)(conjunction)(independent clause)

What is a rigorous way to separate complex and a compound sentences? Imagine if you were to write a computer program. Roughly speaking, how would a computer tell the difference?

- `We listened eagerly` , for `he brought news of our families.` (compound)
- `We listened eagerly` , `for he brought news of our families.` (complex.)
- `She didn’t speak to anyone`, and `nobody spoke to her` (the `and` operator excluded from the second clause)
- `She didn’t speak to anyone`, `and nobody spoke to her` (the `and` operator included in the second clause)
- `I don’t expect children to be rude`, nor do `I expect to be disobeyed`
- `The mother sat` and `the baby slept` (compound -- `and` operator excluded from the second clause)
- `The mother sat` `and the baby slept`  (complex -- including the `and` operator inside of the clause makes the clause dependent)
- `The mother sat` while `the baby slept`
- `The mother sat` `while the baby slept`
- `I washed the car` after `I came home` (compound. the word "`after`" is an operator)
- `I washed the car` `after I came home` (complex... `after` and `I came home` got lumped together)
- `I will go shopping` , or `I will go camping` (compound)
- `I will go shopping` , `or I will go camping` (complex ... "`or`" is a subordinating conjunction)

In mathematics we would usually split up the string "`4 + 3`" as "`(4)(+)(3)`," not "`(4)(+ 3)`." The whole idea of a "dependent clause" is very foreign to me. Why would you choose to lump together the operator with one of the operands?

What scheme do you use to decide whether a sentence is "compound" or "complex?"

Comment: "Complex" means the number contains both real and imaginary values.

Comment: @HotLicks while I understand your joke, it does not help me to understand. In math class, if `10 + x^2 = 0`, then `x` is a complex number, but not a real number. I understand that the word "complex" means something different in English than it does in math. My question was basically, if you made a mathematical model of compound and complex sentences how would you define the difference?

Answer (score 3):

As a mathematician, I would feel very, very suspicious about an explanation made to “appeal to a mathematical mind”. Especially since I know that English *is complicated* and trying to press it into simple rules is going to fail.

Comment: I have a bachelor's degree in math. I share your belief that the rules governing English was far more complicated than the rules in mathematics. Trying to create a mathematical model the entire English language in mathematics would be a daunting. However, I chose one "bite-sized" piece of English. The goal is simply to tell the difference between a compound sentence and a complex sentence. That is a small enough task, that I think can explanation can be made to appeal to a mathematical mind.

Comment: Although math and computer science are different disciplines, it would be sufficient to describe pseudo-code that would accept a well-formed, grammatically correct, sentence as input and output one of the two words, "compound" or "complex."

Comment: I think you need to study formal grammars.These originated in the 1950s (if my memory serves) as an attempt to mathematise natural language. It  was soon discovered that this was much more difficult than expected. Nevertheless formal grammars became a subject of research.  There are whole disciplines based on the analysis of natural language - look up Natural Language Processing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing I don't think you will get a short answer here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar#History

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me as if a dependent clause is simply an independent clause and conjunction lumped together.

**Be careful.** This may be true in some cases, but not in all cases.

Now, the distinction between a complex and a compound sentence lies with the conjunction. A compound sentence uses a **coordinating conjunction**, because the two clauses - both *independent* - are of equal importance. A complex sentence uses a **subordinating conjunction**, because the two clauses are of different importance: one is *independent* and the other is *dependent*.

Most of your sentences are *compound sentences*. They can't be changed into complex sentences by "drawing the boundaries" wherever you like. This is because they utilize coordinating conjunctions, and this doesn't change by including or excluding them.

If a computer were tasked with differentiating between compound sentences and complex sentences, searching for conjunctions would be a good way to start (the other way would be to check for independent/dependent clauses, which I think requires intuition that a computer cannot possess).

Comment: Suppose that `S1` is the text "`Sarah laughed and she entered the room.`" `S2` is text "`and she entered the room.`" Is `S2` a dependent clause inside of `S1`? Note that the word "`and`" is a coordinating conjunction.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon If it's a coordinating conjunction, S2 can't be a dependent clause. Coordinating conjunctions join two clauses **of equal importance**. _She entered the room_ is an independent clause: it contains a subject and a predicate. When you write it by itself, it's a complete sentence. The reader isn't left thinking "What happened?" Change the sentence to "Sarah laughed **as** she entered the room" and the sentence becomes complex.

Answer (score 0):

In the previous answer, note the important distinction between "sub"ordinating and "co"ordinating. "Sub" means "under" or "secondary to"; "co" means "equal to" or "of equal weight or value". In a complex sentence, the writer can use different kinds of clauses to indicate which information is the more important: the information in a subordinate clause is of secondary weight to the information in the main clause. On the other hand, in a compound sentence, the information in each of the two clauses is of equal weight or value. One finer point of syntax: in a compound sentence, you can decide which clause is first, which second, depending on which you think should come to the reader's attention first. Mathematically, I think of the equal sign = versus the other signs (greater than >, less than <, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The rules in [KINDS OF SENTENCES AND THEIR PUNCTUATION](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentences.htm#dependent%20clause) might help (examples omitted):

> A sentence may be one of four kinds, depending upon the number and type(s) of clauses it contains.
>
> - An independent clause  contains a subject, a verb, and a complete thought.
> - A dependent clause contains a subject and a verb, but no complete thought.
>
> #### 1. A SIMPLE SENTENCE has one independent clause.
>
> Punctuation note:  NO commas separate two compound elements (subject, verb, direct object, indirect object, subjective complement, etc.) in a simple sentence.
>
> #### 2. A COMPOUND SENTENCE has two independent clauses joined by
>
> - A.  a coordinating conjunction (for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so),
> - B.  a conjunctive adverb (e.g. however, therefore), or
> - C.  a semicolon alone.
>
> Punctuation patterns (to match A, B, and C above):
>
> - A. Independent clause, coordinating conjunction  independent clause.
> - B. Independent clause; conjunctive adverb, independent clause.
> - C. Independent clause; independent clause.
>
> #### 3. A COMPLEX SENTENCE has one dependent clause (headed by a subordinating conjunction or a relative pronoun ) joined to an independent clause.
>
> Punctuation patterns:
>
> - A.  Dependent clause,  independent clause
> - B.  Independent clause  dependent clause
> - C.  Independent,    nonessential dependent clause,     clause.
> - D.  Independent    essential dependent clause     clause.
>
> #### 4. A COMPOUND-COMPLEX SENTENCE has two independent clauses joined to one or more dependent clauses.
>
> Punctuation patterns:
>
> Follow the rules given above for compound and complex sentences.
> A compound-complex sentence is merely a combination of the two.
>
> #### CONNECTORS--COMPOUND AND COMPLEX SENTENCES
>
> Two independent clauses may be joined by
>
> - 1. Coordinating conjunctions         Ic,  and    ic
> - 2. Conjunctive adverbs       Ic;    therefore,     ic.
>
> A dependent (subordinate) clause may be introduced by
>
> - 1. Subordinating conjunctions (ADVERB CLAUSE)     Dc, ic.   or    Ic dc.
> - 2. Relative pronouns (ADJECTIVE CLAUSE)  I, dc,  c.    or      I  dc  c.
> - 3. Relative pronoun, subordinating conjunctions, or adverbs (NOUN CLAUSE)

Mathematical examples:

```
x=7 and y=5        (compound: two independent ideas)
x=7 or x=5 or x=3  (compound: three independent ideas)
x=7 therefore x>0  (complex: the second idea depends on the first)
x=7 and y=5 therefore x+y=12 (compound-complex)
x+y=10 and x-y=2 therefore x÷y=1½ (compound-complex)
```

Or think of it as:

- Compound sentences can be listed in point form (e.g. "all of the following are true:" or "at least one of the following is true:")
- Complex sentences cannot be listed in point form without changing the meaning of the sentence (e.g. the last example above would lose the idea of the 1½ having been deduced from the first two values).